# Horizontal LinearLayouts in Vertical LinearLayout, last line height not working,why?

Tags: java, android, height, android-linearlayout

I have a vertical linearlayout in my activity, and many dynamically added (in code, not xml) horizontal linearlayouts in it. There are several textview in the horizontal linearlayouts.
I set the height of the textviews by command line, and the height of every single textviews are the same.
Everything works fine, except the final horizontal linearlayout: its height is compressed to let the text in its textviews to show in the vertical center. (almost half of its height should be displayed out of the cell phone screen, which is the exact effect i want)
why its height automatically shrink? How can i get the effect i want?

Comment: This is the screenshot, please check  [link](http://i.stack.imgur.com/6jL3Y.png)

Comment: I've added the screenshot to the question.